# Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I'm trying to send email using laravel 5.4 but I'm getting this error.
I try to enable less secure application for my account but nothing seems to work for me.  this is my code:

```
use Mail;

class UserController extends Controller{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $inputs=$request->all();
        $data=$inputs;
        Mail::send('mail.ajout', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->subject("Nouvelle inscription");
            $message->to('myaccount@gmail.com');
        });

    }
}
```

my env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME= myacount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD= mypwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

mail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],  
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

any help please ,thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your `mail.php`?

Comment: What is your `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there space in after .env variable `=` ? Then just remove it takes space as a character.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=myacount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After changing `.env` clear your config and restart your server.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan serve
```

Comment: i remove space and  restart server but still the same error

Comment: Something wrong with gmail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213283/swift-transportexception-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-mes/46213484?noredirect=1#comment79390614_46213484